# Custom listview doesnot show all data present in my List

Tags: android

Here is the Adapter class that doesn't work properly.
It always shows me 3 rows even if I'm passing 5 values in List as an parameter.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem in my adapter class.
        Any help will be greatly appreciated.
        Thanks:)

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import com.example.mis.R;

        import com.mis.adapter.Chk_Model;
        import com.mis.database.DatabaseHandler;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.CheckBox;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class ThreeTextViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        List<String> orderNum=new ArrayList<String>();
        TextView txtOrd1,txtShip1,txtStatus;
        DatabaseHandler handler;

            public ThreeTextViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> ordNo) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                super(context, R.layout.threetextview,ordNo);
                this.context=context;
                this.orderNum=ordNo;
                handler=new DatabaseHandler(context);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
                final int pos = position;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                            R.layout.threetextview, parent, false);
                    viewHolder.txtOrd1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst_detail_expo);
                    viewHolder.txtShip1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsec_detail_expo);
                    viewHolder.txtStatus=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtthird_detail_expo);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

                }
                else {
                     viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView
                            .getTag();

                }

                viewHolder.txtOrd1.setText(orderNum.get(pos));

                handler.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor=handler.getShipNo(orderNum.get(pos));
                handler.closeDatabase();

                String shipNo=cursor.getString(0);
                if(shipNo.equals(null))
                {
                    viewHolder.txtShip1.setText("Not Exported");    
                    viewHolder.txtStatus.setText("Failed");

                }
                else
                {
                viewHolder.txtShip1.setText(shipNo);
                System.out.println("y"+shipNo);

                viewHolder.txtStatus.setText("Passed");

                System.out.println("z"+"Passed");
                }
                return convertView;
            }
            private static class ViewHolder
            {
                TextView txtOrd1,txtShip1,txtStatus;
            }

        }
```

Here, I have attached my code where I'm initializing my adapter.
I have converted Set to list.

```
   Set<String> keySet = ordShipNo.keySet();
    Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        ordExported.add(ordShipNo.get(key));

    }

    adapter = new ThreeTextViewAdapter(this, ordExported);
    lststatus.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my Xml layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_full_mpr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="189dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_fullTitle_mpr_mpr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#267ad4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_OrderLstOrdNo_mpr"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pn"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_ShipNo_mpr"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/receipt_no"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_status_mpr"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/st"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_msefullresult_mpr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_mseOkResult_mpr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this the custom layout of 3 textviews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtfirst_detail_expo"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsec_detail_expo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtfirst_detail_expo"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtthird_detail_expo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you overriding the getCount method? That might help

Comment: Are you updating the list after creating the adapter?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are initializing the adapter?

Comment: No,I m not overiding getCount method

Comment: No i,m not updating the List

Comment: Can you try printing the size of the list in adapter constructor/or debug and confirm if the size is 5?

Comment: I had attached the code where i'm initializing my Adapter

Comment: I tried by printing the size of the list it is coming correctly 5 but displaying only 3 rows.

Comment: Hmm this is weird..Log/print the  `position` inside getView function to check how many times the getView is called.

Comment: And the position? Does it print `4` at all (Try scrolling till end)?

Comment: Btw calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` isn't necessary since you have not updated the data after setting adapter. - This isn't fix for the problem though.

Comment: When i'm passing List as 4 values to list it is calling the getview method for 12 times with position values as 0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0 @Abhishek V

Comment: So getView is calling for position 3. There should have been 4 rows then. Must be some problem in getView implementation.

Comment: In the code above when i commented the holder.txtStatus both (in if and else) then the adapter inflates correctly all the List value...But as i Uncomment that same only 3 rows got displayed..@Abhishek V

Comment: I wonder how commenting that line will fix the issue! Can you post the code for `threetextview` xml layout?

Comment: Instead of directly sending "Passed" or "Failed" in adapter...i'm sending value by placing it in a variable it worked for me...like this..String Pass="Passed";
  Really confused WHY!!!@Abhishek V

Comment: If that is the case then even I am confused then :p Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

As Jorge suggest, overRide getCount of your adapter like this and return the size of the list.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return orderNum.size();
    }
```

and if it failed to solve the problem, then give me your code where you setting the adapter to the listView.

Comment: This isn't necessary if custom adapter extends `ArrayAdapter`. I think it is some other issue.

Comment: I tried with getCount() method also but it doesn't work

Comment: As AbhisheK Said, Confirm the count of the data by using Log.

Comment: I confirmed it...it is ok